# How to filter accidental keystrokes caused by my cat?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

What really iritates my cat is, when I'm sitting and - totally concentrated - staring on the monitor screen. I can understand that - it must look stupid.

He has figured out a way to deal with that. He would walk over my keyboard, filling my source-code with giberrish, pausing or rewinding my movies or sending emails before I'm finished writing.

It can also happen to me to press some keys accidentally when moving the computer, placing something on the keyboard or when I put notebook on keyboard in order to write something.

As I think of it, I never seem, during usage of my PC, to press multiple keys that are next to each other. Cat paw however, as well as anything else put on the keyboard is almost bond to do that.

Could I use some sort of key filtering software to filter out these accidental key-presses? Is there any such software that is scriptable to do exactly what I want?

Comment: When I'm reading, my cat will come and lay down over the book :)

Comment: @Ramhound actually there is software that does that.  Check the duplicate link.

Comment: Well, computer can tell, if you teach him, that keys pressed near each other. That is the key. The only question is, how much work do *I* have to do. I'm a programmer, but there will be lot's of *WINAPI* nasty stuff I'd like to avoid.

Comment: And I'm asking for software solution. What works on cat's will not work on other accident (such as pressing keys by object placed on keyboard).

Comment: possible workaround: bind a key to disable all other keys, except 1 key that enables all keys again. Whenever you take a break or watch a movie: disable key. Then let the cat program!

Comment: That would be wery useful for other purposes as well. For example, cleaning the keyboard without turning the PC off. Currently, I switch on desktop before doing that.